# Home automation project with cherrypy: display information on a single web interface

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am on a home automation project which gathers a number of modules (control of lamps, motion detection, video flow, door's opening detection ...). All my scripts having been written in python, my choice was ported to cherrypy for the web part (the real reason being that I do not know PHP well). I would like to build a web interface, with cherrypy, which will serve as a dashboard to control the various modules. I am able to call my functions from the interface, but the return processing is every time returned on a new generated HTML page, not on my dashboard as I would like.
More concretely, here is a minimal code to explain my problem:

```
<form method="get" action="aff">
<button type="submit" >clic</button>
```

This is a snippet of my HTML code that displays a button to call the "aff" function when clicked.

```
class principal(object):
 @cherrypy.expose
 def index(self):
  return open('MySite.html')

 @cherrypy.expose
 def aff(self):
  return """ <h1> IT'S WORK </h1> """
 if name == 'main':

  cherrypy.quickstart(principal(), '/', config)
```

Then there is my python-cherrypy code that retrieves my HTML file and makes it accessible from a browser. It contains a "aff" function which is called when the button is pressed and returns a text: "IT'S WORK".
At this level what I want is that this text is displayed on the main page of the site (index) but what happens is that my text is returned on a new page, with the URL that changes to: 127.0.0.1:8080/aff.

The question is, how do I make the result (my text in this case) displayed on my main page?

Comment: Any reason you're not using Flask or any other web framework?

Comment: Anyway, try `form method="post"`

Comment: When you use 'regular' HTML, there will be always a reload and the new content is displayed. I think you want cherrypy act as a rest server and you need a Javascript framework (angular.js, vue.js ... or minimun jQuery) to build a single page application, that will load the data from cherrypy in the background (ajax/xhr) and updates your HTML/DOM.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers!  I just tested the POST method and the result is exactly the same as with the GET method. While browsing the official documentation of Cherrypy, I discovered that both methods can be used indifferently, the result will be the same.                                                                             @Maurice The approach you are proposing seems interesting. I'm just studying the jquery, which means I'm still a great beginner. So, a clue on how to proceed to update dom with jquery?

Comment: Google: 'jquery xhr tutorial' :)

Comment: Somewhere down the road you might want to also look into [ws4py](https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python/), which integrates really well with CherryPy. So you can push new data from the server (instead of pulling from the client).

Comment: Also you may want to re-render the same web-page for simplicity. In this case use some templating engine (say jinja2), add both a form/button to the same template with a conditional clause for data. You may use cherrypy handler accepting POST request if your form sends some data. Otherwise, use simple GET and you probably don't need a form in such case

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, but cherrypy seems more and more difficult to take charge, especially because of the lack of documentation provided on the web. Even the official documentation did not help me a lot, because all the examples offered (sending data with ajax, updating dom with jquerry, ...) did not work for me. This may be because of my version of python (3.6) which is not well supported, so I decided to switch to flask which is very well documented and easy to tackle.